# SQL query to fetch the count for all the possible transitions in a table

Tags: sql

Given a set of database records that record the timestamo when an object enters a particular state, I would like to produce a query that shows the count and the list of all the transitions.

I have a table like the following that records the date when an object enters a particular state:

```
ObjID Timestamp                        State
----- ----------                       -----
A     2022-09-14 09:00:00.000001       1
A     2022-09-14 09:00:00.000002       2
A     2022-09-14 09:00:00.000003       3
A     2022-09-14 09:00:00.000004       4
B     2022-09-14 10:00:00.000001       1
B     2022-09-14 10:00:00.000002       2
C     2022-09-14 11:00:00.000001       1
C     2022-09-14 11:00:00.000002       2
```

I need to produce a query that returns the count of objects for all the transitions. The result would look like the following:

```
State                Count
-----                ----
1->2->3->4           1
1->2                 2
```

As there are two objects for which the state transitions happened from 1 to 2 and one object for which the state transition happen from 1->2->3->4

I have tried below query, but this is will return only transition from 1->2->3->4, but there are rows where the transition can be 1->2->3 or 1->2 or 1->2->3->4->5. So I am not sure how to handle all the permutations in the query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  from Table T1,
       Table T2,
       Table T3,
       Table T4
 WHERE T1.ObjId = T2.ObjId
   AND T1.ObjId = T3.ObjId
   AND T1.ObjId = T4.ObjId
   AND T1.Timestamp < T2.Timestamp
   AND T2.Timestamp < T3.Timestamp
   AND T3.Timestamp < T4.Timestamp
   AND T1.State = 1
   AND T2.State = 2
   AND T3.State = 3
   AND T4.State = 4
```

Can anyone please help in this regard.

Comment: Why did you tag your question with 2 different rdbms tags? Do you use db2 or mysql? It's easy to do this in db2 with the LISTAGG function. Look at the db2 docs for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For DB2, you can use `LISTAGG()`:

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jpwvzBiD)

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
    ObjId, 
    LISTAGG(State, '->') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Timestamp) AS State
FROM table
GROUP BY ObjId
)

SELECT
    State,
    COUNT(1) AS Count
FROM cte
GROUP BY State
ORDER BY State DESC
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not needed - you group by this column at the previous step, so the values in this column are unique. `COUNT (1)` is enough.